# MemoryStream - OutOfMemoryException when trying to allocate space

Tags: c#, memorystream

I'm attempting to take a large file, uploaded from a web app, and make it a memorystream for processing later. I was receiving OutOfMemory exceptions when trying to copy the HttpPostedFileBase's inputstream into a new MemoryStream. During troubleshooting, I tried just creating a new MemoryStream and allocate the same amount of space (roughly) as the length of the InputStream (935,638,275), like so:

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(935700000);
```

Even doing this results in a System.OutOfMemoryException on this line.

I only slightly understand MemoryStreams, and this seems to be something to do with how MemoryStreams buffer data. Is there a way for me to get all of the data into one MemoryStream without too much fuss?

Comment: Why a memory stream? If you are going to process it later, why not just copy it to the temp folder? Storing such a big data in memory (Resulting in allocating 800MB s of memory for a file) is not a good design decision in my opinion, no offense.

Comment: Allocating such a large chunk of contiguous memory can only ever work when you remove the jitter forcing.  Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the processing involves, but the HttpPostedFileBase already contains a stream with the data. You can use that stream to process what you need to do.

If you really need to move back and forth or multiple times over the stream, and the input stream does not support seeking/positioning, you may want to stream the data to a temporary local file first and then use a file stream to do your processing against that file.

If many people uploading via your web app, the array size you specified would quickly eat up all memory using a MemoryStream.